# Java send Stack trace to different output stream

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace

I need to log a stack trace when I catch an exception in my Java app.  I know that exceptions have a built in `printStackTrace()` method, and that that can send the stack trace to a different PrintWriter/PrintStream, but it would be useful if I could grab the stack trace as a String so that I can manipulate it or display it in a JMessagePane or something.  Currently, the only way I have to do this is:

```
String stackTrace = "";
stackTrace += e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() + "\n";

for (StackTraceElement elt : e.getStackTrace()) {
    stackTrace += "\tat " + elt + "\n";
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the `printStackTrace` method does much more than the alternative suggested in the question body. That is, it includes the stacktrace for the cause if one is set and excludes any `StackTraceElement` from the cause that is common to the original exception, hence the phrase `... <int> more`

Comment: excellent point.  That is another reason that I want more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
String stackTrace = writer.toString();
```

Answer (score 4):

using commons-lang :

```
String stackTrace = ExceptionUtils.getStacktrace(e);
```

javadoc : [`ExceptionUtils.html#getStackTrace()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#getStackTrace%28java.lang.Throwable%29).